# Is it possible to see who logged on to my work laptop with Dameware?

Tags: windows-7

I am a software developer and while I was working on some code I believe someone may have accessed my computer via Dameware, either on accident or purposefully, and ended up deleting some code. I am wondering if it is possible to see who had logged on to the computer during this time, or if there is a log of Dameware activity stored on my computer somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

You can find this in the Windows System Logs --  **Computer Management / Event Viewer / Windows Logs / Application**

Look for Event ID 111 (Source:dwmrcs)

When you look at the details of the event you will see the Computer & User Name of the person that connected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Diagnostics tool for DRS/MRC consoles is called Remote Support Diagnostic. It can be found in the Windows menu.

> Click Start > All Programs \Solarwinds\DameWare Remote
>   Support\Help\Support Tools > Remote Support Diagnostics

After executing it, just click Start and it will collect all logs and pack them into .zip file.

Comment: What if I do not have the particular folder? I am not seeing Solarwinds or DameWare in my program files.

Comment: @PhoenixFly what rdp client is being used then?

Comment: It is DameWare that is being used, but I am assuming the specific program file is being stored elsewhere? Is that possible?

Comment: @PhoenixFly have you checked your program files? And if applicable program files (x86).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps
1-)  Go to the hidden system tray icons to look for Dameware
2-)  Dameware shows as 2 little monitors either green/red or red/red
3-)  Find the tiny icons and right click on them, on the top it will show an option to see "Who is connected..." you will be able to see who it is

Regards,

Ana Q